# How to get all count of mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I know the count of a model that data has been saved? there is a method of `Model.count()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myApp');
var userSchema = new Schema({name:String,password:String});
userModel =db.model('UserList',userSchema);        
var userCount = userModel.count('name');
```

`userCount` is an Object, which method called can get a real `count`?

***Thanks***

Comment: If you're using ES 2016, you can wrap the call to count inside of a promise and call it with a generator.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The code below works. Note the use of [countDocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments).

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myApp');
 var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name:String,password:String});
 var userModel =db.model('userlists',userSchema);
 var anand = new userModel({ name: 'anand', password: 'abcd'});
 anand.save(function (err, docs) {
   if (err) {
       console.log('Error');
   } else {
       userModel.countDocuments({name: 'anand'}, function(err, c) {
           console.log('Count is ' + c);
      });
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 174):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the count function is asynchronous, it doesn't synchronously return a value.

Here's an example of usage:

```
userModel.count({}, function( err, count){
    console.log( "Number of users:", count );
})
```

Comment: Give me example to get count synchronous way of method

Comment: Same for me. I am looking for the same

Comment: `count` method is depricated, you can use `countDocuments` same syntax

Comment: @KirNovak Thanks bro. I also provided the url in mongoose for the [deprecation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count).

Answer (score 51):

You should give an object as argument

```
userModel.countDocuments({name: "sam"});
```

or

```
userModel.countDocuments({name: "sam"}).exec(); //if you are using promise
```

or

```
userModel.countDocuments({}); // if you want to get all counts irrespective of the fields
```

For the older versions of mongoose, use

```
userModel.count({name: "sam"});
```

Comment: DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, you should use .estimatedDocumentCount() or .countDocuments() instead.

Comment: countDocuments is the right one according to the docs from mongoose ;), thanks

Answer (score 33):

The collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use collection.**countDocuments** or collection.**estimatedDocumentCount** instead.

```
userModel.countDocuments(query).exec((err, count) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }

    res.json({ count: count });
});
```

Comment: here is the documentation link : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount

Comment: I had the problem, that in our project a setup routine tests for existing items in any collections. The count() method behaved strange: when the collection was not empty, it sometimes returned nothing (undefined, null, zero or false - we could not investigate it further). We still did not find out what caused the problem since it was a race condition that happend very seldomly. Using countDocuments({}) now works for us. Thank you!

Comment: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: userModel.countDocuments is not a function` I get an error when using it on my own userModel?

Comment: How can we make "userModel.countDocuments" as synchronous call so that I can add a virtual to the schema that adds some "key & value" in my document.

Answer (score 24):

## Background for the solution

As stated in the mongoose documentation and in the answer by Benjamin, the method [`Model.count()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) is deprecated. Instead of using `count()`, the alternatives are the following:

**[`Model.countDocuments(filterObject, callback)`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments)**

Counts how many documents match the filter in a collection. Passing an empty object {} as filter executes a full collection scan. If the collection is large, the following method might be used.

**[`Model.estimatedDocumentCount()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount)**

This model method estimates the number of documents in the MongoDB collection. This method is faster than the previous `countDocuments()`, because it uses collection metadata instead of going through the entire collection. However, as the method name suggests, and depending on db configuration, the result is an estimate as the metadata might not reflect the actual count of documents in a collection at the method execution moment.

Both methods return a mongoose query object, which can be executed in one of the following two ways. Use `.exec()` if you want to execute a query at a later time.

## The solution

### Option 1: Pass a callback function

For example, count all documents in a collection using `.countDocuments()`:

```
someModel.countDocuments({}, function(err, docCount) {
    if (err) { return handleError(err) } //handle possible errors
    console.log(docCount)
    //and do some other fancy stuff
})
```

Or, count all documents in a collection having a certain name using `.countDocuments()`:

```
someModel.countDocuments({ name: 'Snow' }, function(err, docCount) {
    //see other example
}
```

### Option 2: Use `.then()`

A mongoose query has `.then()` so it’s “thenable”. This is for a convenience and query itself is not a promise.

For example, count all documents in a collection using `.estimatedDocumentCount()`:

```
someModel
    .estimatedDocumentCount()
    .then(docCount => {
        console.log(docCount)
        //and do one super neat trick
    })
    .catch(err => {
        //handle possible errors
    })
```

### Option 3: Use async/await

When using async/await approach, the [recommended](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#should-you-use-exec-with-await?) way is to use it with `.exec()` as it provides better stack traces.

```
const docCount = await someModel.countDocuments({}).exec();
```

*Learning by stackoverflowing,*

Comment: Awesome answer!

Answer (score 9):

Using mongoose.js you can count documents,

- count all

```
const count = await Schema.countDocuments();
```

- count specific

```
const count = await Schema.countDocuments({ key: value });
```

Answer (score 4):

The highest voted answers here are perfectly fine I just want to add up the use of **await** so that the functionality asked for can be achieved:

```
const documentCount = await userModel.count({});
console.log( "Number of users:", documentCount );
```

It's recommended to use **countDocuments()** over 'count()' as it will be deprecated going on. So, for now, the perfect code would be:

```
const documentCount = await userModel.countDocuments({});
console.log( "Number of users:", documentCount );
```

Answer (score 4):

`Model.count()` method is deprecated in mongoose version 6.2.0. If you want to count the number of documents in a collection, e.g. `count({})`, use the `estimatedDocumentCount()` function instead. Otherwise, use the `countDocuments()` function instead.

`Model.estimatedDocumentCount()` Estimates the number of documents in the MongoDB collection. It is Faster than using `countDocuments()` for large collections because estimatedDocumentCount() uses collection metadata rather than scanning the entire collection.

Example:

```
const numAdventures = await Adventure.estimatedDocumentCount();
```

reference : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount

Answer (score -1):

As said before, your code will not work the way it is.  A solution to that would be using a callback function, but if you think it would carry you to a 'Callback hell', you can search for  "Promisses".

A possible solution using a callback function:

```
//DECLARE  numberofDocs OUT OF FUNCTIONS
     var  numberofDocs;
     userModel.count({}, setNumberofDocuments); //this search all DOcuments in a Collection
```

if you want to search the number of documents based on a query, you can do this:

```
 userModel.count({yourQueryGoesHere}, setNumberofDocuments);
```

setNumberofDocuments is a separeted function :

```
var setNumberofDocuments = function(err, count){ 
        if(err) return handleError(err);

        numberofDocs = count;

      };
```

Now you can get the number of Documents anywhere with a getFunction:

```
     function getNumberofDocs(){
           return numberofDocs;
        }
 var number = getNumberofDocs();
```

In addition , you use this asynchronous function inside a synchronous one by using a callback, example:

```
function calculateNumberOfDoc(someParameter, setNumberofDocuments){

       userModel.count({}, setNumberofDocuments); //this search all DOcuments in a Collection

       setNumberofDocuments(true);


}
```

Comment: In function calculateNumberOfDoc(), why are you calling setNumberofDocuments(true) ?
Would it not result in error first, even before the actual count is returned??