# Node.js: How to execute count command in mongoose.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, mongoose

For example, I want execute count command like:

```
db.test.count()
```

or  group?

How can do it in `mongoose.js`?

By the way, how can I execute aggregate command in mongoose? it seems doesn't have `runCommand`

Comment: Check out the response here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10814388/1135590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose is built on the the ["mongodb" nodejs driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/).  Therefore Mongoose's coding patterns generally look more like this driver than the Mongo CLI.  In particular most calls are asynchronous and require a callback to get results.  In addition to almypal's example in his comment here is an [aggregate example](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/t9RfGqQvby8).

Answer (score 0):

On the mongodb client you can use `db.<collection>.find().cound()` to accomplish it.