# Mongodb count issue, object object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a node.js server that calls a function that needs to query a Mongodb database.

```
exports.zonetotal = function(db) {
  return function(req, res) {
    var inZone1 = 2;
    inZone1 = db.collection('driveby').count();
var items = [
    {"zone":"1" , "number":inZone1}
 ]; 
    {
      res.json(items);
    }
  }
};
```

When I try to use this function and display the results in a table on a webpage i just get a  result that says object object. If I just say var inZone1 = 2; then the number displays so I do not think that it is an issue with the way I am trying to send the data, I think that it is an issue with the query. Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: You mean when you console.log the response right? But what to you see as the actual response or if your use JSON.stringify on the parsed object instead?

Answer (score 1):

collection.count() is asynchronous.  You need to provide a callback that performs the render.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811887/how-to-get-a-all-count-of-mongoose-model).  Just move your rending code inside the callback like so:

```
db.collection('driveby').count({zone:1}, function(err, count) {
  console.log(count + "records in db");
  console.log("There are " + count + " records in db");
  var items = [ {"zone":"1" , "number":count} ]; 
  res.json(items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Node MongoDB driver is async, so you'll need to pass a callback to "count" and execute res.json from within the callback:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#count

Comment: How would I go about passing a callback within the callback?