# How to get number of documents using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a Nodejs/Express/Mongoose app, and I wanted to implement an autoincrement ID features by incrementing the number of recorded documents, but I'm not able to get this count, cause Mongoose 'count' method doesn't return the number:

```
var number = Model.count({}, function(count){ return count;});
```

Is someone managed to get the count ? Help please.

Comment: Duplicate, see more discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811887

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The count function is asynchronous, it doesn't synchronously return a value. Example usage:

```
Model.count({}, function(err, count){
    console.log( "Number of docs: ", count );
});
```

You can also try chaining it after a `find()`:

```
Model.find().count(function(err, count){
    console.log("Number of docs: ", count );
});
```

UPDATE (node:25093 - DeprecationWarning):

using count is deprecated and you can also use "Collection.countDocuments" or "Collection.estimatedDocumentCount" exactly the way you used "count".

UPDATE:

As suggested by @Creynders, if you are trying to implement an auto incremental value then it would be worth looking at the **[mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment)** plugin:

Example usage:

```
var Book = connection.model('Book', bookSchema);
Book.nextCount(function(err, count) {
 
    // count === 0 -> true 
 
    var book = new Book();
    book.save(function(err) {
 
        // book._id === 0 -> true 
 
        book.nextCount(function(err, count) {
 
            // count === 1 -> true 
 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It works that way, but I wanted to get the count back within a variable so that I can increment that variable:

Comment: @kaizer Understand that the count function is asynchronous and can finish at any time so the variable `number` will be undefined when you're accessing it. You can only use the values inside the `count` function's callback.

Comment: @kaizer It seems you're trying to implement an auto incremental value? You can use the [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment) plugin for this.

Comment: @Creynders you've got it man, thx, I'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 18):

If you are using node.js >= 8.0 and Mongoose >= 4.0 you should use `await`.

```
const number = await Model.countDocuments();
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 15):

If anyone's checkin this out in 2019, `count` is deprecated. Instead, use `countDocuments`.

Example:

`const count = await Model.countDocuments({ filterVar: parameter }); console.log(count);`

Answer (score 3):

If your collection is large - use `Model.estimatedDocumentCount()`. It's faster then `count` and `countDocuments`, because it doesn't scan the entire collection.

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.estimatedDocumentCount

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are expecting `var number` to contain the count value. In your callback function you are returning `count` but this is executed asynchronously so will not assign the value to anything.

Also, your first parameter in your callback function should be `err`.

For example:

```
var number = Model.count({}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count); // this will print the count to console
});

console.log(number); // This will NOT print the count to console
```

Answer (score -2):

you hava to wait the callback function

```
Model.count({}, function(err , count){
  var number = count;
  console.log(number);
});
```

in JavaScript

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('a');
}, 0);

console.log("b");
```

the "b" will be printed before "a"
because

```
console.log('a')
```