# Vue update data within mongoose database and using axios call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios

I have a problem, I used a get and post function to retrieve and save some url in my database, but now I d like to update a variable count, that should rapresent the votes that every video get, and after that I shoul be able to disable the button that a user click to vote. So I'm having some troubles to make the update function, or I should use another post? But if so I probably create another element inside my DB or not?

so here there is my video and for now I set the video's id invisible using css, to test it and try to find the video with that specific id and make the update

```
                <p class="invisible" id="idVideo"> {{item._id}} </p>

                <iframe class="partecipant"  v-bind:src="item.video.url"> </iframe>

                <p id="voti" > {{item.voti.count}}  </p>

                <input type="button" id="buttonVoti" v-on:click="addVoto">
```

so here, when the user click the button with id= buttonVoti the v-on click call addVoto function

```
methods: {
...
//ALL THE OTHERS METHODS
...
...
...
 //AND THEN THE ADDVOTO FUNCTION
 addVoto : function () {
                            var self = this;
                            //self.videos[1].voti.count++
                            //console.log(self.videos._id);
                            var i = document.getElementById("idVideo");
                            var idVid =i.innerHTML;
                            console.log(idVid);
```

so here I can change the variable count, using self....count++ but I have to store and then retrieve again the same video with the new count updated.

here there is my model so the logic to access to the count should be this one

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var videoSchema  = new Schema({

     video : {
         id : String,
         url : String,
         idchallenge :  String
     },

     voti : {
         count : {}
     }
     });


 module.exports = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema);
```

yes so I have a method called load video, that is activated when the user click a button called loadVideo

```
                  loadVideo : function (){


                        var linkYoutube = this.text;
                        console.log(linkYoutube);

                        //POST
                        axios.post('/video',{

                            method: 'post',
                            video: {
                                id: '1',
                                url: linkYoutube
                            },
                            voti: {
                                count: 0
                            }

                        });
```

and this is my get function,

```
                        getVideo: function () {
                        var self = this;

                        // Make a request for a user with a given ID
                        axios.get('/video')
                            .then(function (response) {

                              self.videos = response.data;
                                console.log(self.videos);
```

Comment: Can we see the function that makes the request to your server? It should be the `POST` you are referring to. Can we also see the Mongoose function you use to get all your videos and their votes? I assume it is the `GET` method you are referring to.

Comment: All right I edited the question and these are my get and post methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you do you `GET` request to your video route, in your route logic, you should be able to use [Mongoose count](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count). Here is what that route might look like:

```
var Router = require('express').Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Video = mongoose.model('Video');

Router.get('/videos', function(req, res) {
    var response = {};

    Video.find({}, function(queryErr, videos) {
        if (!queryErr) {
            response.videos = videos;

            Video.count({}, function(countErr, count) {
                if (!countErr) {
                    response.count = count;
                    res.status(200).send(response);
                } else {
                    res.status(500).send(countErr);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(500).send(queryErr);
        }
    });
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Here is a question about Mongoose count on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811887/how-to-get-all-count-of-mongoose-model).