# How to get collection's count in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/myDB');
```

there is collection `users` in myDB, how can i get number of documents in `users`?

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811887/how-to-get-all-count-of-mongoose-model

Comment: @chridam thank you, that's what I was looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all count of mongoose model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811887/how-to-get-all-count-of-mongoose-model)

Comment: @MikaS yeah, ure right, i have already understand how it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you even tried to do this yourself?

None the less,

```
db.open (function(error){
    db.collection("users", function(error, collection){
        collection.count({}, function(error, numOfDocs) {
            console.log(numOfDocs + ' total users');
        });
    });
});
```

That should get you started, I ahven't tested this code but I remember doing it like that.

Comment: i have tried, and i don't understand your code, but it works. Can you leave a link to docs about the `count` ?

Comment: Sure, here we go, [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) and [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)


Just to explain the code for you, db.open opens the connection to your MongoDB database.


db.collection('Users'...) will select the users collection, and will return the collection in the collection variable when found.


collection.count, uses that returned collection to count the number of documents, and then returns it in numOfDocs.

Comment: but why i should write exactly that? is this the only way? if i want to get just number,  should  i write this huge code?

Comment: @epsilon Because you have to instruct your computer what to look for. You could look at tools to manage your database, it could make querying a little bit easier perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

try this way, its a snippet from my dummy code and it should work

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');   // Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connection.once('open',(db)=>{         // opens the connection for us
    console.log("Connection made to mongodb");
    mongoose.model('<collection>').count().then((count) => { // replace <collection> with collection name
            console.log(count);
    })
}).on('error',(error)=>{
    console.log("connection error to mongodb : " + error);
});
```